# Difference static behaviour between MyClass.class and Class.forName(“MyClass”)

Tags: java, class, static

I'm not sure what's the difference of loading static variables/blocks between `MyClass.class` and `Class.forName("MyClass")`, for example, I have below class:

```
package test;
public class SampleClass{
    public static SampleClass instance = new SampleClass();
    private SampleClass(){
       System.out.println("SampleClass Instance Created");
    }
}
```

Then, in another class, I accessed the class object of above SampleClass by using:

```
System.out.println(SampleClass.class);
```

Then, the output will be:

```
class test.SampleClass
```

If I changed to use `class.forName()`, as below:

```
 System.out.println(Class.forName("test.SampleClass"));
```

Then, the output will be:

```
 SampleClass Instance Created
 class test.SampleClass
```

Does anybody can give me an explanation?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should see "SampleClass Instance Created" in both cases. Perhaps it was earlier in your log than you expected?

Comment: [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)) should help you

Comment: @JonSkeet Unfortunately, this is not the case. [JLS 12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) clearly states the events that leads to _class initialization_. Accessing a class with `.class` is no such event. So there is a difference in class loading between these two statements: Only the latter initializes the class!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: Doh - I had misread the code; I thought the OP was printing out the `instance` itself. I blame a lack of coffee.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Yup, I'd misread the code. Sorry!

Comment: @JonSkeet You can have some of mine. I have plenty of coffee because here in Germany daily work already has started. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The call to the `Class.forName("MyClass")` causes the class to be loaded at runtime. JVM also initializes that class after the class has been loaded by the classloader, so `static` blocks get executed.

In your case you have a static field which is the instance of your class, as this static block get executed your object is being initialized. That's why you are seeing the System.out get printed.

The `.class` syntax is used to get the `Class` of the called class. It doesn't not load the class actually.

### Reference:

- [What does Class.forname method do?](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17)
- [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-)
- [Retrieving Class Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html)

Comment: I had seen the same sourcve as you. :) I just was too slow. +1

Answer (score 2):

`Class.forName()` uses the ClassLoader and tries to resolve class name at runtime, while `.class` is resolved at compile time.

Comment: That's true, but doesn't explain the difference in whether the class is *initialized* when it's found. Note that even using `.class`, the class is still *loaded* at execution time.

Answer (score 1):

`class.forName()` loads the class using the "caller's" class loader if the class is not already loaded.

`.class` doesn't load the class.

Comment: Using the class literal *loads* the class, but doesn't *initialize* it. For example, if you delete the class file for `SampleClass` before running the program, you'll get a failure as the class can't be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Its is just because of `Class.forName()` is dynamically loaded at run time your class into memory(RAM). and it will execute all static block within this class without creating reference of that class,

From offical doc:

> A call to Class.forName("X") causes the class named X to be dynamically loaded (at runtime). A call to forName("X") causes the class named X to be initialized (i.e., JVM executes all its static block after class loading). Class.forName("X") returns the Class object associated with the "X" class. The returned Class object is not an instance of the "x" class itself.
>
> Class.forName("X") loads the class if it not already loaded. The JVM
>   keeps track of all the classes that have been previously loaded. This
>   method uses the classloader of the class that invokes it. The "X" is
>   the fully qualified name of the desired class.

here is more information about it: http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-does-classforname-method-do/17

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all above for your answers and discussions.

I thought the class will be loaded no matter using Class.forName() or MyClass.class, obviously I'm wrong. But I don't understand why it doesn't load the class when using MyClass.class.